Place different objects on curve with exponential space between

Hello everyone, how can i place all these different(!) objects to the curve, with using empty as a space, rotation and location controller between them, but exponential increments or decrements.
As it does object offset function in array modifier.
Tried to make it in geometry node but have not enough knowledge

one way is using geometry nodes with this node tree:

so you resample the curve with the number of points of your collection of instances and then you reposition these points (set position) mathematically via the sample curve node, which spits out the position. The factor input is going from 0 to 1. If you give this not equidistant values, but e.g. powered values, you will get:

Hope it helps. Happy blending.
